# (C++) Самоудаление dll возможно?

Tags: c++

Возможно ли сделать самоудаление dll при возвращении DLL_PROCESS_DETACH?

То есть, при выгрузке динамической библиотеки из процесса происходило непосредственно самоудаление этой dll'ки.

примерно вот так:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        SelfDelete();
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Что-то вряд ли... Если только чем-то внешним удалять типа батника или планировать удаление на перезагрузку.

Comment: В Windows вряд ли - сам файл все еще заблокирован процессом.

Comment: Можете подсказать пример через батник?

Comment: что то типо такого: цикл пока не удалится файл

Comment: Вполне возможно. Только так делать не следует. А вообще этот вопрос скорее похож на проблему XY. Зачем вам вдруг понадобилось удалять ее из dllmain?

Comment: Вы меня видимо не так поняли) Есть специальная dll, где в секции с DLL_PROCESS_DETACH выполняется функция удаления этой самой специальной dll. Т.е. самоудаление dll, которая была загружена, и позже после выгрузки самоудалялась. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Если бы это была OS/2 - там была штатная функция API, которая загоняла файл в память и разлочивала его. Так что EXE/DLL могли удалять сами себя. В Windows, пока файл выполняется - а он в этот момент выполняется - он залочен и все попытки его убить ничего не дадут. Так что, как написал Qwertiy...

Comment: Впрочем, попробуйте `MoveFileEx` с флагом `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` - см. [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa)

Comment: Harry, мне нужна именно функция самоудаления файла для dll, которая будет срабатывать при выгрузке этой самой dll из процесса. Как я понимаю - это невозможно. Но смотрите. Есть такая функция для самоудаления исполняемого файла - https://paste.in/VyKml4 , быть может, ее как нибудь можно переписать и под динамическую библиотеку?